How can I revert the redesigned strange-looking text cursor after a Sonoma upgrade?
An issue I noticed is that there is a funny cursor locator blinker when using TextEdit app in the new Sonoma MacOS version.

It is now an orangey colour and slightly wider. Awful aesthetics. How do I change it all back the way it was???

Which 'new Sonoma macOS version' are you referring to, 14.1, 14.2, etc? A good practice is to explicitly state which version you refer to, as future readers are unlikely to go to the trouble of cross-referencing your post-date to release dates. Please update your question.

It's the AppleAccentColor of the app. You can override it on a per-app basis as described in Is there a way to set macOS' accent color on a per-app basis?.
Or just disable the macOS Sonoma new insertion point altogether with sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/FeatureFlags/Domain/UIKit.plist redesigned_text_cursor -dict-add Enabled -bool NO as described in Disable macOS Sonoma Text Insertion Point (Cursor) / Caps-lock Indicator.
Update: The featureflags hack no longer works since macOS Sequoia 15.0.

doesn't seem to work on Sequoia 15.1.1

@MartinKlosi Indeed. I updated the answer.

It is set by Settings | Appearance | Highlight Color. Your perception of width difference is likely due to the change in colour.
I don't know whether this is a recent change, with no previous system to compare with, but the above is correct with macOS 14.5
